# Variable only updated in the sendAsynchronousRequest

Tags: swift, sendasynchronousrequest

Example of what i wan't to do:

```
var b  = 0

let URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "[URL to php file]")!
let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
{
    (response, data, error) in
    b = 5
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return b //Return 0
}
```

I know that in numberOfRowsInSection it return 0 cause the sendAsynchronousRequest execute after 
but is there a way to make the numberOfRowsInSection function execute after the sendAsynchronousRequest ? Or is there a better way to make my variable equal 5 before numberOfRowsInSection function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to delay the `numberOfRows...` call, but you can call `tableView.reloadData` once you've received the data in your asynchronous request:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
{
    (response, data, error) in
    b = 5
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

That will make the table view reconfigure itself and call `numberOfRows...` again.